# Django filter does not accept database fields

Tags: django, filter

Using Django 4.1.2, filtering does not work for database fields.

Given the following model:

```
class Activities(models.Model):
    es_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ef_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ls_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    lf_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Migration done and DB content can be retrieved, for instance it gives back all of them properly:

```
>>>from mymodel.models import Activities
>>>Activities.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Activities: Task 33>, <Activities: Task 30>...]>
```

or requesting a particular item also works properly:

```
>>>Activities.objects.get(id=1)
<Activities: Task 1>
```

although applying filter for a given field it drops "**NameError**" error

```
>>>Activities.objects.all().filter(es_date>timezone.now())
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'es_date' is not defined
```

What might be the error?

Comment: Yes, it results the same "NameError"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```py
Activities.objects.all().filter(es_date__gt=timezone.now())
```

and check the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [__gt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt):

```
Activities.objects.all().filter(es_date__gt=timezone.now())
```